# Mysql query for non stored Value from table

Tags: ios, mysql, sqlite, mobile-application

I have table with below details

```
userTbl

id | name
1  | user1  
2  | user2
```

above is userTbl table details ,

below is a query,

```
Select * from userTbl where id = 1 or id = 2 or id = 3 or id = 4
```

I should get only **3 , 4** as result.

is it possible in mysql? (SQLite mobile database -in iOS)

thanks in advance.

Comment: i can explain more specific?...even there is no records of 3 and 4 how can you get...can you describe clear?

Comment: Do you have another table you're comparing to, or just value literals?

Comment: Are you really running MySQL on an iOS device?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're working with literal values, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4
) t
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM userTbl);
```

If the values you're looking for come from another table, we can make this much cleaner with a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT id
  FROM otherTbl o
  LEFT JOIN userTbl u ON o.id = u.id
 WHERE u.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this i hope this is your requirement...any how your question is not clear

```
select * from userTbl where id in(1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: Hi i wanna get non stored values, from above table i want to get  3 and 4 because its not in table. i hope you under stand.